# Java leapyear check program. No response to edge values

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm working on a program for school to take a year input from the user and check to see if it is a leap year or not. It should also check to see if the year is prior to 1582 and return an error if it is. I'm having an issue that if the user enters a year between [1582, 1599] that the program halts and doesn't print anything. If I change the value to 1600 it doesn't return anything between [1600, 1639]. Not sure why this behavior is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Leapyear {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Jeff = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.print("Run Leapyear progra? Enter true or false:  ");
        //boolean RunLoop$ = Jeff.nextBoolean();
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a year:  ");
        int Year = Jeff.nextInt();
        //while(RunLoop$ = true)
        if (Year <= 1582)
            System.out.println("The entered year is prior to the Gregorian Callandar");
        else
        if (Year % 4 == 0)
            if (Year % 400 + Year % 100 == 0)
                System.out.println("The entered year is a leapyear");
            else
                System.out.println("The Entered year is not a leapyear");
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using `{` and `}` characters for EVERY `if` statement.  Never rely on the scope of an `if` being just the statement below it.  If you do that, you'll see immediately what you've done wrong here.  Failing that, you could try stepping through with a debugger, which will help you understand what's happening.

Comment: Thanks David! . That seems to have resolved the issue. I'll have to read more on if statements to better understand this issue.

Comment: The problem was that the scope of the second `if` statement was all four following lines, but you wanted it to be just the next two.  In other words, the final `else` got paired up with the wrong `if`.

Comment: Incidentally, your logic is incorrect - it won't show the "correct" answer for leap years other than those that divide 400.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements are incorrect. I second David's comment and strongly advise to use brackets for *every* `if` statement (which is also recommended in the - albeit ancient, but mostly still valid - [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html)). 
Furthermore, switching to a decent IDE and/or making use of its source code formatting support will greatly help you with these kinds of issues.

A simple (automatic) cleanup leads to the following snippet for your `if` statements, which is fully equivalent in terms of application logic:

```
if (Year <= 1582) {
    System.out.println("The entered year is prior to the Gregorian Callandar");
} else if ((Year % 4) == 0) {
    if (((Year % 400) + (Year % 100)) == 0) {
        System.out.println("The entered year is a leapyear");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The Entered year is not a leapyear");
    }
} // else?
```

You can now clearly see that there won't be any output if `Year` is greater than 1582 but not divisible by 4.

Comment: The code conventions are old, but they are certainly not outdated.

Comment: Thanks Marvin. That definitely helps to visualize how the layout was causing some numbers to not output. I guess it hadn't occurred to me that the issue was with numbers not divisible by 4. I'll need to spend some more time on visualizing the interaction between if statements apparently!

Comment: @LewBloch Well, not maintained for the past years, so at least _potentially_ outdated. But I basically agree and changed the remark - hopefully for the better ;)

Comment: Yes, it's better. There are many standard Java coding conventions, but they're all based on the granddaddy you linked. Variations exist for curly-brace placement, indentation, what gets spelled like a constant name, and other criteria, but none of the widespread ones deviate very far from the original. I'm aware of none that permit the dollar sign `$` in names.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't use the {} curly brackets for every if and else statement then it will only consider the first line after the condition so in

```
else
[empty line]

if (Year %4 ==0)
 [empty line]
```

means after else it will do nothing the same after the if because only the first line under it is considered which is empty.

Another problem you'll be having is that your while loop will go forever :) since the boolean value will always remain true. If you want to make user insert a new value each time then just insert at the **end** of the while loop.

```
System.out.print("add another year ? ");

RunLoop$ = Jeff.nextBoolean();
Year = Jeff.nextInt();`
```

or add `Jeff.hasnextInt()`in the while loop condition instead removing the Boolean entirely so when user enters anything other than an int value the loop breaks.`while(Jeff.hasnextInt())` and at the end of the loop.

```
System.out.print("add another year ? ");
 Year = Jeff.nextInt();`
```

Comment: Thanks for the headsup on the loop Omar. Honestly It was something I had just been playing with while I worked on the if statement issue. I had it commented off most of the time since I wasn't finished working on it yet.